# Xcode tag users in image

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, image, tags

I want to make something similar to facebook tag mechanism. I will display an image of a building to the users and i want them to be able to tag themselves in which room they are at the moment. The location would be sent to a web server so all users can see other's location. Is that possible and how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely to be possible.
I can suggest the following solution: store the building photo/scheme AND rooms information on server.
In your App, you will display image (perhaps in ScrollView), there you will have just TapGestureRecognizer which will recognize the room, depending on coordinates of tap.
In case of this solution, you will have to manually store information about each tap-zone corresponding to a room. But that's the most likely case.

Comment: The problem is that depending on user's selection the displayed image will be different. So we have to find an "automatic" way that keeps the coordinates of user's tap. Can somehow store the coordinates for the corresponding image to database and then in the app displaying all the coordinates for the image as a pin or something??? Would that work?